# Filtering output of json with multiple if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json that has keys of ver, price and level.
In my html there are 3 radio buttons for ver, and 3 checkboxes for each price and level. I have attached an change event that will only output or filter the sample obj which can be a combination depending on the checkedbox of price and level. 
am I filtering my result right?
What I'm expecting to be my output when checked: If I choose ver = 1 ,price = 1, and level = 1 it should output 2 objects.

```js
var obj = {
 "sample" :[
    {"ver": "1", "price":"1", "level": 1},
    {"ver": "0", "price":"2", "level": 2},
    {"ver": "1", "price":"1", "level": 1},
    {"ver": "1", "price":"3", "level": 3},
    {"ver": "1", "price":"1", "level": 1},
    {"ver": "0", "price":"2", "level": 1},
    {"ver": "1", "price":"3", "level": 3}
  ]
}

var priceArr = [];
var levelArr= [];
var out;

var price = $("input[name='price']").change(function(){
  var checked = $(this).val();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        priceArr.push(checked);
        return priceArr;
  }else {
        priceArr.splice($.inArray(checked, priceArr),1);
        return priceArr;
  }
});
var level = $("input[name='level']").change(function(){
  var checked = $(this).val();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      //convert string val to int
      levelArr.push(parseInt(checked));
      return levelArr;
    }else{
      levelArr.splice($.inArray(checked, levelArr),1);
      return levelArr;
    }
});


$("input[type='radio'][name='ver'], input[name='price'], input[name='level']").change(function(){
  var r = $("input[type='radio'][name='ver']:checked").val();
  var p = price;
  var l = level;
  sortResult(r,p,l);

 });

 function sortResult(r,p,l){
  p.sort();
  l.sort();

  if(r != undefined && p != "" && l != ""){
    obj.sample.map(function(i){
        if (i.ver == r){
            //filter the price in which they belong to
            if( i.price == p[0] && i.price == p[1] && i.price == p[2]){
                //output price that is filtered
                console.log(i.price)
              if(i.level == l[1] || i.level || l[2] || i.level == l[2] ){
                //output level that is filtered 
                console.log(i.level) 
              }
            }
        }
        output =  '<div>Ver '  + i.ver   +'</div>';
        output += '<div>Price' + i.price +'</div>';
        output += '<div>Level' + i.level +'</div>';
    });//map
  }//if
}//sortResult
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form >
    <div><input type="radio" name="ver" value="0" >All</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="ver" value="1" >ver1</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="ver" value="2" >ver2</div>
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form >
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="1" >Price 1</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="2" >Price 2</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="3" >Price 3</div>
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form >
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="level" value="1" >Level 1</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="level" value="2" >Level 2</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="level" value="3" >Level 3</div>
  </form>
</div>


<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: First, if you are using `.map`, please return something from it and accept this return value somewhere. Second, can you shed more light on `i.price == p[0] && i.price == p[1] && i.price == p[2]`

Comment: Also you snippet is throwing error.

Comment: @Rajesh Sorry, fixed the error. From the html user can choose any price. The second if statement is to ouput only the price which is chosen in the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {
 "sample" :[
    {"ver": "1", "price":"1", "level": 1},
    {"ver": "0", "price":"2", "level": 2},
    {"ver": "1", "price":"1", "level": 1},
    {"ver": "1", "price":"3", "level": 3},
    {"ver": "1", "price":"1", "level": 1},
    {"ver": "0", "price":"2", "level": 1},
    {"ver": "1", "price":"3", "level": 3}
  ]
};

function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
  var checkboxesChecked = [];
  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].value);
     }
  }
  // Return the array if it is non-empty, or null
  return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : [];
}


$("input").change(function(){
  var r = $("input[type='radio'][name='ver']:checked").val();
  var ver = r == 0 ? null : r - 1;
  sortResult(ver,getCheckedBoxes("price"),getCheckedBoxes("level"));

 });

function sortResult(r,p,l){
    obj.sample.map(function(i){
        if (p.indexOf(i.price) >= 0 && l.indexOf(i.level+"") >= 0) {
          if (r && i.ver == r){
            console.log(i);
          } else if (!r) {
            console.log(i);
          }
       }
    });
}
```

Truthfully there was a lot of edge cases that your code wasn't handling, p and l were functions instead of arrays. Even those weren't forming correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks for the idea can you explain to me why is your if statement condition like this?
if(p.indexOf(i.price) >= 0 && l.indexOf(i.level+"") >= 0) why is should be equal or greater than 0 and why is i.level + "".

Comment: Sure,  
1) In most computer languages indexing of arrays begin at 0, in comparison to the lingual 1 for arrays in the real world.
2) In the HTML tag for input you had kept value as a string rather than an integer, so converting in your response to the same.